# Use system-installed package with spacemacs that depends on MELPA packages

Tags: init-file, spacemacs, package-repositories

How can I include a package that is available locally on my system that depends on the string library `s` with spacemacs?

I have an company internal package that adds functionality to magit available at `/usr/share/emacs-config/neat-tool.el`

`neat-tool.el` is something like:

```
;;; neat-tool.el --- Use neat tool

(require 'magit)
(require 's)
(magit-define-popup-action 'magit-dispatch-popup ?x
   "Neat commands"
   'neat-commands-popup)
```

I have a custom layer called `my-layer` with a `packages.el` of:

```
(defvar my-layer-packages
  '((neat-tool
     :location (recipe
                :fetcher url
                :url "file:///usr/share/emacs-config/neat-tool.el"))))

(defun my-layer/neat-tool ()
  "Init neat-tool."
  (use-package neat-tool
    :defer t
    :init
    (with-eval-after-load 'magit
      (require 'neat-tool))
    ))
```

Unfortunately, this fails with `Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, s`.  `s` is correctly installed and up to date in `~/.emacs.d/elpa`

I could wrap another `with-eval-after-load` in the `:init`, but that seems messy.  Is there a better way to declare the dependency on `s`?

Comment: Not sure how the spacemacs init is layed out, but is it possible to call `package-initialize` earlier? If `s` is installed via melpa, then that should setup its autoloads.

Comment: I ran into the same issue and found that I could individually activate and load the library I needed, does this answer help? https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/36826/5495

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `s` to `dotspacemacs-additional-packages` in your init file? If so, require should find it as emacs is not doing relative loading (like e.g. npm).

Comment: That didn't actually work for me (in my case for `general.el`, not `s.el`) because spacemacs defers package activation.  See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/36826/5495