# autoload of general.el not working in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, autoload

I have this in my personal spacemacs layer's `packages.el`:

```
(setq mylayer-packages
      '(general
        (mylayer :location local)
        evil-org
        ))
```

Then later in the same file:

```
(defun mylayer/post-init-evil-org ()
  (spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-minor-mode 'evil-org-mode
    "ot" 'counsel-org-tag
    )
  (general-define-key
   :states
   '(normal)
   :keymaps 'evil-org-mode-map
   "O" 'mylayer/either-O-or-org-open-above
   "o" 'mylayer/either-o-or-insert-heading-respect-content
   )
  )
```

When I start spacemacs (conventionallly configured: `~/.emacs.d` is a symlink to my spacemacs git repo), I get this:

`An error occurred while post-configuring evil-org in layer mylayer (error: (void-function general-define-key))`

general-autoloads.el is there in the package directory as I expected:

`spacemacs/elpa/25.1/general-20171106.818/general-autoloads.el`

I expected that emacs would have read that autoload file at startup before my layer's post-init function for evil-org was read, and that I would therefore be able to call `general-define-key`.

What's going on, and how can I avoid the error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that spacemacs' `init.el` defers package activation.  Package activation involves reading `<package>-autoloads.el` files so that e.g. the elisp for `general-define-key` gets loaded when it's first called (otherwise, emacs knows nothing about that function).  That normally happens because emacs calls `(package-initialize)` automatically, unless there is a special comment in `init.el`.  Spacemacs uses that special comment, does `(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)`, and calls only `(package-initialize 'no-activate)`, and then explicitly activates packages one-by-one, as a means of optimizing startup time.

It seems that if you need some package for use as a library, you must therefore arrange for it to be activated yourself.

I suspect the following is not the most "spacemacsy" answer possible: perhaps there is some way to tell spacemacs you need a library during the spacemacs startup process, in a way that's more declarative.

Until somebody points that way out, this seems to work for me (though I'll also point out that I'm not yet sure how well spacemacs and `general.el` will play together):

```
(defun mylayer/post-init-evil-org ()
  ;; here's what I added to make use of general.el work
  (package-activate 'general)
  ;; end of what I added
  (spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-minor-mode 'evil-org-mode
    "ot" 'counsel-org-tag
    )
  (general-define-key
   :states
   '(normal)
   :keymaps 'evil-org-mode-map
   "O" 'mylayer/either-O-or-org-open-above
   "o" 'mylayer/either-o-or-insert-heading-respect-content
   )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice detective work investigating Spacemacs's treatment of `package-initialize`! However, I believe the "spacemacsy" solution would simply be

```
(defun mylayer/init-general ()
  (use-package general))
```

If you want `general` to be lazy-loaded, you can probably just add `:commands (general-define-key)` to the `use-package` declaration. (Disclaimer: I have no idea how `use-package` interacts with "traditional" Emacs autoloads in e.g. `general-autoloads.el`...)